# issue to inject java code into an <aui:select> control (with <% %> or <%= %> )

Tags: java, jsp, drop-down-menu, liferay, liferay-aui

I find odd results while testing  form control.

Normal select control:

```
<select class="form-control " name="input_nb_players_min" id="input_nb_players_min">
<%out.write(   "<option value=\"test3\" label =\"test3\" />"         ); %> //works fine
<%= "<option value=\"test6\" label =\"test6\" />" %>//works fine
<%System.out.println(   "<option value=\"test3\" label =\"test3\" />"   );%>    //works fine   
</select>
```

when doing the same into an < aui:select>:

```
< aui:select name="preferences--mailingSendMode--" type="select" label="type d'envoi du mailing"  value="<%= mailingSendMode_cfg %>" >
    <%out.write(   "<aui:option value=\"test3\" label =\"test3\" />"         ); %>
    <%="<aui:option value=\"test4\" label =\"test4\" />" %> //not working!
    <aui:option value="test2" label ="test2" />    //works fine   
    <aui:option value="test" label ="test" />   //works fine    //not working!
    <%= "<aui:option value=\"test6\" label =\"test6\" />" %> //not working!
    <%String str =  "<aui:option value=\"test7\" label =\"test7\" />"; %>
    <%=str %> //not working!
    <%System.out.print("test/>"); %> //working
    <aui:option value="test8" label ="test8" selected="<%=true %>" />   //works fine   
    <aui:option value="test9" label ="test9" selected="<%=1==1 %>" />   //works fine   

 </aui:select>
```

Can anyone share light onn this pls?

thx in advance.

Comment: I don't know **exactly** what happens but, seeing the code i think that the taglibs (such as `<aui:select>`) are resolved **before** the rest of jsp is compiled.

So your `<aui:option>` inside `<%= %>` are not resolved in plain HTML. Let's see if somebody can tell us something more specific.

Comment: What are you trying to do dynamic list of Options?

Comment: Writing strings of "taglibs" out to the response isn't going to work. Taglibs need to be parsed at the JSP level. I would suggest you look into JSP and taglibs and how to properly use them.

Comment: @GUISSOUMA Issam
Right now, I only want to include either "selected = true" or "selected = false" . I was planning to inject the correct string into the <aui:option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the code below as an example of dynamic options with a selected value:

```
<aui:select name="title">
    <%for(int i = 0; i < listOfOptions.size(); i++){ 
        Object option = listOfOptions.get(i);
        boolean selected = false;
        if(user.getTitle().equals(option.getTitle())){
            selected = true;
        } %>
        <aui:option label=<%=option.getTitle() %> value="<%=option.getValue() %>" selected=<%=selected %> />
    <%} %>
</aui:select>
```